# No persistence providers available for "transactions-optional"

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, jdo, datanucleus

I'm having this error in my AppEngine project:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No persistence providers available for "transactions-optional" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:180)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:70)
```

**jdoconfig.xml**

```
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig_3_0.xsd">

    <persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional">
        <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass"
            value="org.datanucleus.api.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.singletonPMFForName" value="true"/>
    </persistence-manager-factory>
</jdoconfig>
```

Its really weird since in my jdoconfig.xml there is this "transactions-optional"

Answer (score 0):

Obviously JPA (which you use to get an EMF) doesn't use "jdoconfig.xml" (which is used by JDO). JPA uses "persistence.xml". Suggest you decide which API you're using before going further

Comment: Hi @DataNucleus I have the same problem but I am using JPA <persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">       <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider> <properties><property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

Comment: @BabajidePrince or Zybrek, have either of you found the solution to this problem? Your solution may help me solve my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821716/how-to-edit-jdoconfig-xml-and-persistence-xml-so-jpa-saves-to-appengine-datastor.

Comment: Hi, @KatedralPillon I replied see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821716/how-to-edit-jdoconfig-xml-and-persistence-xml-so-jpa-saves-to-appengine-datastor/15827652#15827652 Good luck.