# How to edit jdoconfig.xml and persistence.xml so JPA saves to appengine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa-2.0, google-eclipse-plugin

Using the Google Eclipse Plugin, my project automatically comes with two files inside the META-INF folder: `jdoconfig.xml` and `persistence.xml`. Per the instructions on https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview, my persistence file is supposed to have the following line for jpa datastore storage:

```
<provider>org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jpa.DatastorePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

But when I open the persistence file I found

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
        <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and the `jdoconfig.xml` file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig">

   <persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional">
       <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass"
           value="org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true"/>
       <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true"/>
   </persistence-manager-factory>
</jdoconfig>
```

With those default contents, JPA has not been saving to my datastore. So I edit the `persistence.xml` file to look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
        <provider>org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jpa.DatastorePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

How should I change the `jdoconfig.xml` file? Right now, with my changes to `persistence` but `jdoconfig` as is, I am getting a huge error trace.

redacted error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)

…
…
...

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No persistence providers available for "transactions-optional" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:180)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:70)
```

Comment: Since the instruction does not mention a `jdoconfig.xml` file, have you tried removing it and see what happens? I am not an expert on this. I just looked at the instructions to answer.

Comment: I tried that, and many other approaches besides. So far I still having the same problem: data is not persisting to datastore.

Comment: It looks like a few people are having the same problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464991/no-persistence-providers-available-for-transactions-optional).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I am surprised the experts seem to have stayed away (@DataNuclear @bossyLobster)

Comment: I'm sure Google documented all of that https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2#Migrating_to_Version_2.0_of_the_DataNucleus_Plugin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For JPA 2.0 The provider is `org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl` Please note that `persistence.xml` is the configuration file used by JPA and `jdoconfig.xml` is used if you want to use JDO.

You first need to decide what persistence mechanism you want to use, I would assume its JPA so in fact, you can delete `jdoconfig.xml`.

With that been said, make sure all the reguired libs for Datanucleus is in your CLASSPATH and most importantly, persisence.xml must be in the ROOT of your CLASSPATH.

I have added a picture of the lib needed for a successful JPA 2 / Datanucleus persitence.

Also make sure your enhancer is correctly configured.

FYI: I could never get Google Eclipse Plugin to work with JPA 2, the entity enhancements never worked so I used maven. There are several ways to enhance your classes and maven is one.

Here is my pom.

```
    <properties>
            <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
            <gwtVersion>2.5.0</gwtVersion>
            <gxtVersion>2.2.5</gxtVersion>
            <gae.version>1.7.5</gae.version>
            <datanucleus.version>3.1.3</datanucleus.version>
            <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.5 -->
            <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>

    <!-- DN -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
            <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1  </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-jsr107cache</artifactId>
  <version>${gae.version}</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
  <version>${gae.version}</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.jsr107cache</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsr107cache</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

For the enhancements, add the following to plugins section of your pom:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <api>JPA</api>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>             
                     <mappingIncludes>**/entity/*.class</mappingIncludes>
                     <fork>false</fork>
                     <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Change `<mappingIncludes>**/entity/*.class</mappingIncludes>` to the package where your entities are placed.

In my own case, DataNucleus Enhancer will look for classes to enhance in package/folder named `entity`.

Good luck

Babajide

[image]